# jsp ul list element dynamic selection

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

here is the situation:
i have a nested ul list in my navigation bar ie

```
<li>
<ul>
<li>
 Some link
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

this is the navigation bar on left of my tiles and in right there is content related to it.

so i want a particular li(main not nested) to be opened whenever i select a nested li.
how to do it , by any way css or javascript.

PS: i am a noob web developer so please suggest easy solutions and there is a possibility that this question have been asked before but i cant find an easy answer, so please don't rate it low.
thanks

Comment: How do you select the nested li element if it's hidden? Or do you mean you want to show the nested ul/li when you select (hover) the parent li element?

Comment: it means if you click on external li then nested li's becomes visible and all i want is to track those nested li's. thanks for taking interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to show it on click, you could use the CSS pseudo Element :target. This is what you basically have to do:

Your HTML Markup: (Give each parent LI a unique ID and the a Element inside the anchor to this element)

```
<ul class="menu clearfix">
    <li id="a">
        <a href="#a">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="b">
        <a href="#b">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="c">
        <a href="#c">Item 3</a>
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Item 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
/* basic menu styling */
ul.menu {
    position:relative;
}

ul.menu li {
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}

ul.menu a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul.menu > li {
    border:1px solid #000;
    min-width:100px;
    margin-left:-1px;
}

/* set up nested ul's and hide them */
ul.menu > li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

/* show them on click */
ul.menu > li:target ul {
    display:block;
}

ul.menu > li > ul > li {
    float:none;
    display:block;
}
```

I put together a small fiddle for [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/MTnCc/).

Comment: hey thanks man!! but i was not looking for this, i want a horizontal list with nested li's open when main li is clicked.

Comment: well now i am using jQuery and all i want now is the position of ul as some number and set that number as an index of ul to be shown.

Comment: @Sachin.Verma use jquery index method http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: i am using it, i got the index . now how to show that particular li related to that index.

Comment: @Sachin.Verma can you provide a fiddle, of what you have.

Comment: function initMenu(){
      $('#menu ul').hide();
      $('#menu ul').index().
      $('#menu ul').show();
      $('#menu li a').click(
        function() {
          var checkElement = $(this).next();
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            return false;
            }
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            return false;
            }});}
    $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});

Comment: @Sachin.Verma I still don't get what was wrong with the CSS/HTML variant I posted, and furthermore, what's wrong with the click action inside your method, which is doing more or less the same as the example I provided. Sorry.

Comment: here is fiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/PbPur/                            the main problem is on actual links instead of # it resets its position to order management ie because of                   "$('#menu ul:first').show();"  , now i want to keep selected the li related to content , please look forward.

Comment: See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/PbPur/2/

Comment: seems perfect , but problem remains , still first ul is shown even i click on anyone's li.

Comment: @Sachin.Verma yes, sure, it is an example, can't work it's just an anchor, so no page reload if you click on it. Test it yourself. Use links inside the navigation, add the anchors to the links (just as it is demonstrated in the example code) and it should work. Or - as I wrote - add a simple GET Param with the corresponding index to each link, and use that one to define the initial open index. Then go on and learn what you do.

Comment: thanks @axel.michel now i understand your solution, thanks again.